# Working on sudoku solver using stacks and backtracking in C++ and need help fixing my algorithm

Tags: c++, if-statement, stack, backtracking, sudoku

Initially my algorithm involved testing every number from 1->n of an nxn sudoku but since it couldn't solve 16x16 sudokus (had the algorithm running for 3 hours with no luck) I thought it would be better to choose numbers in a cell based on the most valid and least used number on the board. I think I've figured out most of it, e.g. I made a 2D vector called usage (first column is number and second is usage) which I sort every time I make a change on the board. Right now I can solve an easy 9x9 and an empty 16x16 but I'm having no luck elsewhere. Wondering if somebody could help me spot where my logic is lacking.

//I used stack <pair<int, int>> to store the most recent row and column we've placed a value in. The first int is the row and the second is the column.

```
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


using namespace std;


bool isRowValid(vector <vector <int>> &sudoku, int row, int possval);
bool isColumnValid(vector <vector <int>> &sudoku, int column, int possval);
int assignBlock9x9(int pos);
int assignBlock16x16(int pos);
int assignBlock25x25(int pos);
bool isBlockValid(vector <vector <int>> &sudoku, int row, int column, int possval);

bool isValidSingle(vector <vector <int>> &sudoku, int row, int column, int possval);


bool isRowValid2(vector <vector <int>> &sudoku, int row, int possval);
bool isColumnValid2(vector <vector <int>>& sudoku, int column, int possval);
bool isBlockValid2(vector <vector <int>>& sudoku, int row, int column, int possval);
bool isValidSingle2(vector <vector <int>>& sudoku, int row, int column, int possval);

int solve(vector <vector <int>>& sudoku);


vector <vector<int>> Usage(vector <vector <int>>& sudoku);
bool sortcol(const vector<int>& v1, const vector<int>& v2);
bool sortcol2(const vector<int>& v1, const vector<int>& v2);

void printSudoku(vector <vector <int>>& sudokusudoku);
void printUsage(vector<vector<int>>& usage);

/* easy sudoku (9x9_1.txt) - actually solves
0 4 0 0 0 0 1 7 9
0 0 2 0 0 8 0 5 4
0 0 6 0 0 5 0 0 8
0 8 0 0 7 0 9 1 0
0 5 0 0 9 0 0 3 0
0 1 9 0 6 0 0 4 0
3 0 0 4 0 0 7 0 0
5 7 0 1 0 0 2 0 0
9 2 8 0 0 0 0 6 0*/

/*solution
8 4 5 6 3 2 1 7 9
7 3 2 9 1 8 6 5 4
1 9 6 7 4 5 3 2 8
6 8 3 5 7 4 9 1 2
4 5 7 2 9 1 8 3 6
2 1 9 8 6 3 5 4 7
3 6 1 4 2 9 7 8 5
5 7 4 1 8 6 2 9 3
9 2 8 3 5 7 4 6 1*/



/*medium sudoku (9x9_2.txt) - can't solve
0 9 0 3 8 4 0 0 0
0 0 2 0 7 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7 1
5 0 0 0 0 3 2 4 0
0 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 5 0 9 0
0 0 0 8 0 0 0 0 0
7 0 6 5 2 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 6 4 0 0*/

/*solution
1 9 7 3 8 4 5 6 2
8 5 2 6 7 1 9 3 4
4 6 3 9 5 2 8 7 1
5 8 9 7 1 3 2 4 6
6 3 4 2 9 8 7 1 5
2 7 1 4 6 5 3 9 8
3 1 5 8 4 7 6 2 9
7 4 6 5 2 9 1 8 3
9 2 8 1 3 6 4 5 7*/


/* hard sudoku (9x9_3.txt) - can't solve
7 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 3
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6 0
8 0 1 0 0 4 0 0 2
0 0 5 0 0 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 4 0 0 0 6 2 0 9
2 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 6
0 3 0 6 0 5 4 2 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0*/

/*solution
7 9 2 5 6 8 1 4 3
4 5 3 2 1 9 8 6 7
8 6 1 3 7 4 9 5 2
6 2 5 8 9 3 7 1 4
3 7 9 1 4 2 6 8 5
1 4 8 7 5 6 2 3 9
2 8 4 9 3 1 5 7 6
9 3 7 6 8 5 4 2 1
5 1 6 4 2 7 3 9 8*/



/* no solution sudoku (9x9_4.txt) - can't solve
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 7
7 2 0 3 0 9 0 0 1
0 0 8 7 0 5 0 6 0
5 0 2 8 9 0 0 0 0
0 4 0 5 0 1 0 9 0
0 0 0 0 6 3 7 0 5
0 3 0 9 0 6 1 7 0
2 0 0 1 0 7 0 5 3
9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
*/

int main()
{
    
    fstream MySudoku("9x9_1.txt");


    vector <vector <int>> sudoku;
    
    //input from text file
    if (MySudoku.is_open()) {
        string row;

        
        while (getline(MySudoku, row)) {
            stringstream rowelement (row);
            string num;
            
            vector <int> row;
            while (getline(rowelement, num, ' ')) {
                if ((int)num[0] >= 65) {
                    row.push_back((int)num[0] - 55);
                }

                else {
                    row.push_back((int)num[0] - 48);
                }
            }
            sudoku.push_back(row);
            rowelement.clear();
            //cout << row;

            //cout << endl;
        }
        

        MySudoku.close();
    }

    
    //input from testing bot
    /*string row;
    int i = 0;
    int rowsize = 9;

    while (i < rowsize) {
        getline(cin, row);
        stringstream rowelement(row);
        string num;

        vector <int> row;
        rowsize = 0;
        while (getline(rowelement, num, ' ')) {
            if ((int)num[0] >= 65) {
                row.push_back((int)num[0] - 55);
            }

            else {
                row.push_back((int)num[0] - 48);
                //cout << 500 + (int)num[0] - 48;
            }

            ++rowsize;
            
        }
        //cout << rowsize;
        sudoku.push_back(row);
        rowelement.clear();

        ++i;
    }
    */

    
    
    
    
    //solving and printing out the resulting sudoku if possible
    int solved = solve(sudoku);

    if (solved == 1) {
        
        printSudoku(sudoku);

    }

    else {
        cout << "No Solution";
    }
}


void printSudoku(vector <vector <int>>& sudoku) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sudoku.size(); i++) {

        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < sudoku.size(); j++) {

            if (sudoku[i][j] >= 10) {

                if (j == sudoku.size() - 1) {
                    cout << (char)(sudoku[i][j] + 55);
                }

                else {
                    cout << (char)(sudoku[i][j] + 55) << " ";
                }

            }

            else {

                if (j == sudoku.size() - 1) {
                    cout << sudoku[i][j];
                }

                else {
                    cout << sudoku[i][j] << " ";
                }
            }

        }

        cout << endl;

    }
}

void printUsage(vector<vector<int>> &usage) {
    
    for (vector <int> usagerow : usage) {

        cout << usagerow[0] << " : " << usagerow[1] << "     ";
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}


int solve(vector <vector <int>>& sudoku) {
    stack <pair<int, int>> solution;
    vector <vector <int>> usage = Usage(sudoku);

    //printUsage(usage);
    

     ///////////initializes solution
    int breaker = 0;
     //pushes value on empty cell
     for (unsigned int row = 0; row < sudoku.size(); row++) {
         if (breaker == 2002) {
             break;
         }
         for (unsigned int column = 0; column < sudoku.size(); column++) {
             if (breaker == 2002) {
                 break;
             }
             
             if (sudoku[row][column] == 0) {
                 //choose option based on usage and then change usage list
                 int vectorpos = 0;

                 while (!isValidSingle(sudoku, row, column, usage[vectorpos][0]) && vectorpos != sudoku.size() - 1) {
                     ++vectorpos;
                 }
                 //cout << usage[vectorpos][0] << " was pushed at " << row << column << endl;
                 sudoku[row][column] = usage[vectorpos][0];
                 usage[vectorpos][1] = usage[vectorpos][1] + 1;
                 sort(usage.begin(), usage.begin() + usage.size(), sortcol);
                 sort(usage.begin(), usage.begin() + usage.size(), sortcol2);

                 solution.push(make_pair(row, column));
                 breaker = 2002;
                 break;
             }
         }
     }
    //printSudoku(sudoku);
    //just prints out the usage vector {not useful}
    //printUsage(usage);
    



    /////actual solution
    bool solved = false;
    while (!solved) {
        //cout << "top of stack is " << solution.top().first << solution.top().second << endl;
        int lastrow = solution.top().first;
        int lastcolumn = solution.top().second;

        //checks if sudoku is in invalid state
        if (!isValidSingle2(sudoku, lastrow, lastcolumn, sudoku[lastrow][lastcolumn])) {

            //copy of usage vector to allow us to see if we're at the last option for the cell
            vector <vector <int>> usagefuture = usage;
            for (vector<int> &usagerowdec : usagefuture) {

                if (sudoku[solution.top().first][solution.top().second] == usagerowdec[0]) {

                    usagerowdec[1] = usagerowdec[1] - 1;
                    sort(usagefuture.begin(), usagefuture.begin() + usagefuture.size(), sortcol);
                    sort(usagefuture.begin(), usagefuture.begin() + usagefuture.size(), sortcol2);
                    break;
                }
            }

            //cout << "future -> ";  printUsage(usagefuture);
            //keeps popping last decision until sudoku no longer in invalid state
            while (sudoku[solution.top().first][solution.top().second] == usagefuture[sudoku.size()-1][0]) {

                //looks for where the last entered value occurs in the usage vector
                int val = sudoku[solution.top().first][solution.top().second];
                for (vector <int> usagerowdec : usage) {
                    
                    if (usagerowdec[0]==val) {
                        //sets cell to 0 and pops
                        sudoku[solution.top().first][solution.top().second] = 0;
                        //cout << usagerowdec[0] << " was set back to 0" /*<< solution.top().first << solution.top().first*/ << endl;
                        solution.pop();
                        
                        //cout << "top of stack is now " << solution.top().first << solution.top().second << endl;
                        //permanently changes the usage vector
                        usage = usagefuture;
                        sort(usage.begin(), usage.begin() + usage.size(), sortcol);
                        sort(usage.begin(), usage.begin() + usage.size(), sortcol2);
                        break;
                    }


                }

                if (solution.size() == 0) {
                    return 0;

                }

                //copy of usage vector to allow us to see if we're at the last option for the cell
                usagefuture = usage;
                for (vector<int>& usagerowdec : usagefuture) {
                    
                    if (sudoku[solution.top().first][solution.top().second] == usagerowdec[0]) {
                        usagerowdec[1] = usagerowdec[1] - 1;
                        sort(usagefuture.begin(), usagefuture.begin() + usagefuture.size(), sortcol);
                        sort(usagefuture.begin(), usagefuture.begin() + usagefuture.size(), sortcol2);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                //cout << "future -> ";  printUsage(usagefuture);

                



            }

            if (solution.size() == 0) {
                return 0;

            }
            else {
                int row = solution.top().first;
                int column = solution.top().second;

                //printUsage(usage);
                //decrements usage vector at value we're changing
                for (vector<int>& usagerowdec : usage) {

                    if (sudoku[row][column] == usagerowdec[0]) {

                        usagerowdec[1] = usagerowdec[1] - 1;
                        sort(usage.begin(), usage.begin() + usage.size(), sortcol);
                        sort(usage.begin(), usage.begin() + usage.size(), sortcol2);
                        break;
                    }
                }

                //printSudoku(sudoku);




                //finds which value we're on in the usage vector
                int vectorpos = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < usage.size(); i++) {

                    if (sudoku[row][column] == usage[i][0]) {
                        vectorpos = i;

                        break;

                    }
                }

                //sees what next value we can set it to. If nothing it becomes the last possible value
                while (!isValidSingle(sudoku, row, column, usage[vectorpos][0]) && vectorpos != sudoku.size() - 1) {
                    vectorpos++;

                }

                //cout << "vectorpos is " << vectorpos << ": ";

                //completes the change
                //cout << sudoku[row][column] << " was changed to " << usage[vectorpos][0] << " at " << row << column << endl;
                sudoku[row][column] = usage[vectorpos][0];
                usage[vectorpos][1] = usage[vectorpos][1] + 1;


                sort(usage.begin(), usage.begin() + usage.size(), sortcol);
                sort(usage.begin(), usage.begin() + usage.size(), sortcol2);
            }


        }



        
        //if sudoku in valid state
        else {
            int breaker = 0;
            
            //looks for empty cell to push to
            for (unsigned int row = 0; row < sudoku.size(); row++) {
                if (breaker == 2002) {
                    break;
                }
                for (unsigned int column = 0; column < sudoku.size(); column++) {
                    if (breaker == 2002) {
                        break;
                    }

                    if (sudoku[row][column] == 0) {
                        //choose option based on usage and then change usage list, worst case is the last value like with the change
                        int vectorpos = 0;

                        while (!isValidSingle(sudoku, row, column, usage[vectorpos][0]) && vectorpos != sudoku.size() - 1) {
                            ++vectorpos;
                        }
                        //cout << usage[vectorpos][0] << " was pushed at " << row << column << endl;
                        sudoku[row][column] = usage[vectorpos][0];
                        usage[vectorpos][1] = usage[vectorpos][1] + 1;
                        sort(usage.begin(), usage.begin() + usage.size(), sortcol);
                        sort(usage.begin(), usage.begin() + usage.size(), sortcol2);

                        solution.push(make_pair(row, column));
                        breaker = 2002;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        //checks if we're at the end
        if (solution.top().first == sudoku.size() - 1   &&   solution.top().second == sudoku.size() - 1){
            solved = true;
            
        }

        
        //printSudoku(sudoku);
        //prints out usage vector {not useful}
        //printUsage(usage);

    }

    return 1;
}



bool isRowValid(vector <vector <int>> &sudoku, int row, int possval) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sudoku.size(); i++) {
        
        if (possval == sudoku[row][i]) {
            return false;
            
        }
    }

    return true;

}

bool isColumnValid(vector <vector <int>> &sudoku, int column, int possval) {
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < sudoku.size(); j++) {

        if (possval == sudoku[j][column]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

int assignBlock9x9(int pos) {
    if (0 <= pos && pos <= 2) {
        return 0;
    }

    else if (3 <= pos && pos <= 5) {
        return 3;
    }

    else {
        return 6;
    }
}

int assignBlock16x16(int pos) {
    if (0 <= pos && pos <= 3) {
        return 0;
    }

    else if (4 <= pos && pos <= 7) {
        return 4;
    }

    else if (8 <= pos && pos <= 11){
        return 8;
    }

    else {
        return 12;
    }
}

int assignBlock25x25(int pos) {
    if (0 <= pos && pos <= 4) {
        return 0;
    }

    else if (5 <= pos && pos <= 9) {
        return 5;
    }

    else if(10 <= pos && pos <= 14){
        return 10;
    }

    else if (15 <= pos && pos <= 19) {
        return 15;
    }

    else {
        return 20;
    }
}

bool isBlockValid(vector <vector <int>> &sudoku, int row, int column, int possval) {

    //if 9x9
    if (sudoku.size() == 9) {
        int startrow = assignBlock9x9(row);
        int startcolumn = assignBlock9x9(column);

        for (int i = startrow; i <= startrow + 2; i++) {

            for (int j = startcolumn; j <= startcolumn + 2; j++) {
                
                if (possval == sudoku[i][j]) {
                    return false;

                }

            }
        }

    }
    //if 16x16
    else if (sudoku.size()==16) {
        int startrow = assignBlock16x16(row);
        int startcolumn = assignBlock16x16(column);

        for (int i = startrow; i <= startrow + 3; i++) {

            for (int j = startcolumn; j <= startcolumn + 3; j++) {
                
                if (possval == sudoku[i][j]) {
                    return false;

                }

            }
        }

    }

    //if 25x25
    else {
        int startrow = assignBlock25x25(row);
        int startcolumn = assignBlock25x25(column);

        for (int i = startrow; i <= startrow + 4; i++) {

            for (int j = startcolumn; j <= startcolumn + 4; j++) {
                
                if (possval == sudoku[i][j]) {
                    return false;

                }

            }
        }

    }
    return true;
}



bool isValidSingle(vector <vector <int>> &sudoku, int row, int column, int possval) {

    if (isRowValid(sudoku, row, possval) && isColumnValid(sudoku, column, possval) && isBlockValid(sudoku, row, column, possval)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}












bool isRowValid2(vector <vector <int>> &sudoku, int row, int possval) {
    int samecount = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sudoku.size(); i++) {
        if (sudoku[row][i] == possval) {
            ++samecount;
        }

        if (samecount == 2) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

bool isColumnValid2(vector <vector <int>> &sudoku, int column, int possval) {
    int samecount = 0;
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < sudoku.size(); j++) {

        if (sudoku[j][column] == possval) {
            ++samecount;
        }

        if (samecount == 2) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

bool isBlockValid2(vector <vector <int>>& sudoku, int row, int column, int possval) {
    int samecount = 0;


    //if 9x9
    if (sudoku.size() == 9) {
        int startrow = assignBlock9x9(row);
        int startcolumn = assignBlock9x9(column);

        for (int i = startrow; i <= startrow + 2; i++) {
            
            for (int j = startcolumn; j <= startcolumn + 2; j++) {
                
                if (possval == sudoku[i][j]) {
                    
                    ++samecount;

                }

                if (samecount == 2) {
                    return false;
                }

            }
        }

    }
    //if 16x16
    else if (sudoku.size() == 16) {
        int startrow = assignBlock16x16(row);
        int startcolumn = assignBlock16x16(column);

        for (int i = startrow; i <= startrow + 3; i++) {

            for (int j = startcolumn; j <= startcolumn + 3; j++) {

                if (possval == sudoku[i][j]) {

                    ++samecount;

                }

                if (samecount == 2) {
                    return false;
                }

            }
        }

    }

    //if 25x25
    else {
        int startrow = assignBlock25x25(row);
        int startcolumn = assignBlock25x25(column);

        for (int i = startrow; i <= startrow + 4; i++) {

            for (int j = startcolumn; j <= startcolumn + 4; j++) {

                if (possval == sudoku[i][j]) {

                    ++samecount;

                }

                if (samecount == 2) {
                    return false;
                }

            }
        }

    }
    return true;
}



bool isValidSingle2(vector <vector <int>> &sudoku, int row, int column, int possval) {

    if (isRowValid2(sudoku, row, possval) && isColumnValid2(sudoku, column, possval) && isBlockValid2(sudoku, row, column, possval)) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}



bool sortcol(const vector<int>& v1, const vector<int>& v2) {
    return v1[1] < v2[1];
}
bool sortcol2(const vector<int>& v1, const vector<int>& v2) {

    return v1[0] < v2[0] && v1[1] == v2[1];
}

vector <vector <int>> Usage(vector <vector <int>> &sudoku) {

    vector <int> usage;
    vector <vector <int>> usage2;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sudoku.size(); i++) {
        usage.push_back(0);
    }

    for (unsigned int row = 0; row < sudoku.size(); row++) {

        for (unsigned int column = 0; column < sudoku.size(); column++) {
            
            if (sudoku[row][column] == 0) {
                continue;
            }

            usage[sudoku[row][column] -1] = usage[sudoku[row][column] - 1] + 1;

        }
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= sudoku.size(); i++) {
        usage2.push_back({(int) i, usage[i - 1] });
    }

    sort(usage2.begin(), usage2.begin() + usage2.size(), sortcol);
    sort(usage2.begin(), usage2.begin() + usage2.size(), sortcol2);
    return usage2;
}
```

Comment: This really could use a [mre]. And a question. Currently you are showing us a fragment of code that does not make much sense without context and making it fairly hard to help you.

Comment: You have adopted an approach to backtracking that seems unfamiliar to me. A primitive backtracking solution for sudoku is: find a free cell, for i from 1 to 9, if i doesn't conflict with anything on the board, put it in, recurse, on return from recursion remove i and try the next value. Once all cells are filled, you're done. -- I don't see the try/backtrack/try something else part of backtracking in yours.

Comment: @dratenik I made sure to copy the whole thing this time thanks for the suggestion. I hope you can see though. It looks good in Visual Studio but now it's not looking so good.

Comment: That certainly is more code. It's not the case that more code will necessarily give you better answers. There is a point to the suggestions in [mre]. Minimal - focus on the 9x9 case, drop 16 and 25, you can generalize later, Complete - can we run it for ourselves? (it should have includes and main as well), Reproducible - does it demonstrate your question? What is your question, actually?

Comment: @dratenik I apologize for not placing all my code. Was busy working on this because today was crunch time. Figured it would be best to just work on it myself over that short period than to bother anyone with something I hadn't properly understood yet.

My question is just to see if anyone can help me spot where my logic is lacking. I tried so hard to get this working but with minimal success.

Minimal - is there much use for that here? Right now i'm only testing 9x9 and to turn from my working 1->n solution to this I just had to change the logic of my algorithm irrespective of sudoku size.